# Query to trim the data from existing mongodb database field

Tags: mongodb, date

I have a field `DateOfBirth` of type `String`. Currently i am storing the `date` in the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss Z`.

Now i want to change the date format in the existing database as `yyyy-MM-dd` i don't want time now i just want to trim that how can i do that using a query in `mongodb`.

```
db.profile.update( {}, { $set : { "physical.dateOfBirth" : "2012-01-11" } }, true, true);
```

I tried using this query i did not get desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot update values based on a current value in mongodd with the exception of increment and decrement.

You will first need to find each value and then update them before saving them again.

You could do it multiple ways:

```
get all profiles (only need _id and properties to update)
for each profile
    set the value to its yyyy-MM-dd value
    save profile
```

or

```
get all profiles (only need _id and properties to update)
create bulkOp    
for each profile
    set the value to its yyyy-MM-dd value
    add update to bulkOp
execute bulkOp
```

or

```
aggregate to find distinct yyyy-MM-dd values
for each <yyyy-MM-dd value>
    var match = {"physical.dateOfBirth": {$regex: <yyyy-MM-dd value>}};
    var update = {$set: {"physical.dateOfBirth": <yyyy-MM-dd value>}};
    var multi = {multi: true};
    db.profiles.update(match, update, multi);
```

Clearly this is just the processes you could try and not actual code.

The last way would be the easiest on memory because you would not actually load much into memory, just the distinct values incase you have 100s or 1000s of values with the same dates.

Good luck

EDIT: something along the lines of this:

The $cond in the _id is just to match everything together in 1 item

```
var aggregate = db.profiles.aggregate({$group: {
    _id: {$cond: ['_id', 'a', 'a']},
    values: {$addToSet: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$physical.dateOfBirth' } }}
}});
var values = aggregate[0].values;


for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var date = new Date(values[i]);
    var nextDay = new Date().setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

    var match = {'physical.dateOfBirth': {$gte: date, $lte: nextDay}};
    var update = {$set: {'physical.dateOfBirth': date}};
    var multi = {multi: true};

    db.profiles.update(match, update, multi);
}
```

Comment: please tell me the query

Comment: What structure does "physical.dateOfBirth" have.
Is it {physical: {dateOfBirth: value}} or {'physical.dateOfBirth': value}?

Comment: it is  {'physical.dateOfBirth':value}

Comment: check update in answer.
May need to be adjusted to whatever language/libraries you are using

Comment: this can be run on mongo DB console? If yes how, If no is there any way to run on console?

Comment: you may be able to use db.eval() to run it on mongoDB but you would have to look into that as I haven't used it myself.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Comment: 2016-11-14T11:15:26.468+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:448  The error is shown for _id: {$cond: ['_id', 'a', 'a']}. When i tried it shows me this error.